# Apple Mac OSX Native applications development with bundled Mysql

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new to MAC OSX development.

Can i use the bundled Mysql in Mac OSX as the database of my application? That means when user install my app, they Mysql database is created and data is being put into the DB automatically. (as if we use SQLite in iOS apps development). And then my app runs on that database from then.

If mysql sql is not a choice, then what we can use instead? SQLite again? Core Data seems to be a nightmare to me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why does Core Data seem like a nightmare to you?

Answer (score 2):

If Core Data seems frightening then that's really only reason to spend time learning it. Core Data has practically become the standard framework used for persisting data in Applications. Sure there are a couple other ones, but you usually get to using those after having mastered Core Data and wanting something more.

Are you going to have problems in Core Data? Yes, but pretty much the same things you'll run into during any development with a persistence framework. Worse if your using SQLite then you have to manually manage memory, migration of data, etc.

If you just have little experience with Core Data and it just seems a little scary I'd really just sit down and take some time to read over Apples guides and documentation on it. Do you have to use it? No, but unless you have a very specific reason chances are that Core Data is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Well said.  Core Data is complex because it solves a complex set of problems in a flexible way.  Odds are it's well worth the time it takes to learn.

Comment: Hi Colin, Thanks for answering.

We have a very safe running applications that relies on MySQL and we hope to port it to the mac platform very quickly.

Basically we need to maintain some Database engine features like view, trigger, etc. We don't want to rewrite all these logic in Objective-C as those are just basic add/edit/delete operations.

If possible, migrating our current DB to SQLite seems to me the resolution? We did that for iOS before but i don't know if we can do the same in MAC OSX platform too. Kindly please provide your advise. Thanks.

Comment: if that's the case then yes you have a very specific need for sqlite in which case you are probably gonna have to convert the database to SQLite and manage it manually. The good news is that most if not all of the code you wrote for iOS should work on Mac OS X as well.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is also on the Mac, but why not use Core Data?

Comment: You can even use SQLite outside of Core Data, if Core Data doesn't fit well for your application.